# Finding the limit of a 2 variables function using epsilon and delta

Tags: limits, analysis

I have been reviewing the notion of limit. With function of one variable, it is perfectly clear and the demonstration make perfect sense to me. I was curious how this would work in the world of two variables.
I have constructed a small example but I got stuck in the middle while trying to find a value for $\delta$.

**Would you mind to finish the demonstration so that I could understand how this is working ?**

$f : \mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ 
$(x,y) \mapsto x^2 + y^2$

Find the limit : $$\lim_{x,y \to (1,1)} f(x,y) = 2$$ 
I started this way : $$ f(x,y) - 2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2 = (x^2 - 1) + (y^2 - 1)$$ 
$$ \lvert f(x,y) - 2 \rvert = \lvert (x+1)(x-1) + (y-1)(y+1) \rvert \le \epsilon$$

This is where I am stucked..

Comment: You should include your definition of the limit of a two-variable function. The particular form of your definition can affect the details of the proof, and in any case it is always good to have the definition in front of you when doing one of these exercises (at least until you're so familiar with it that it is **always** "in front of you" in your head).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a limit is usually extended to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows: for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, we say that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)} f(x,y) = L$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $\lVert (x,y) - (x_0, y_0) \rVert < \delta$. Here $\lVert (x,y) \rVert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the usual Euclidean norm, which generalises the absolute value.

If $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$, we can continue from what you found. Fix $ \epsilon > 0$, and we want
$$
|f(x,y) - 2| = (x^2 - 1) + (y^2 - 1) < \epsilon .
$$
Now, if
$$
\lVert (x,y) - (1,1) \rVert = \lVert (x-1,y-1) \rVert = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta ,
$$
can you see what value of $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ will complete the argument?